# What does the negative sign indicates in the computed checksum value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm computing the hash value using CHECKSUM() function in MS SQL. Why some of the computed values have a positive sign and some of them have a negative sign?

```
SELECT CommodityName, CHECKSUM(CommodityName) FROM Table1
```

Result:

```
CommodityName        Checksum
BuildingSupplies    -1674787472
Cutting Tools        1343439447
Electrical           1703618888
Filtration          -1653028371
PPE                 -2086698034
Spare Parts          1752220254
Welding             -178487827
```

Comment: Because the `CHECKSUM()` can generate a negative number as well as a positive one..

Comment: Okay. Is it argument specific?

Comment: I don't understand - what do you mean argument specific?  `CHECKSUM()` calculates an `INT`-based hash of a value.  An `INT` can be anywhere from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.  So roughly half the time, it will be negative.  I'm not sure the question.

Comment: Example: PPE has negative value. Electrical has positive value. Are signs (negative and positive) given randomly or based on some conditions?

Comment: The output of CHECKSUM doesn't "mean" anything. It's just an opaque token. Some are even and some are odd, that doesn't mean anything either.

Comment: @Madhukar They aren't given "randomly."  And the only condition they have for having a negative sign is... well... being a negative number...

Comment: Also, if you change something, like adding a space between "Building" and "Supplies", the checksum can change completely and go positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment--though it isn't a direct answer of the question. I'm posting since you did state you are computing the hash value.

[This may be of interest to you](http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2011/05/20/do-not-use-only-checksum-or-binary_checksum-as-sole-comparison-in-sql-use-hashbytes.aspx), since you are likely comparing this value against another after the hash.

Specifically... from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788(v=SQL.100).aspx)

> CHECKSUM satisfies the properties of a hash function: CHECKSUM applied
>   over any two lists of expressions returns the same value if the
>   corresponding elements of the two lists have the same type and are
>   equal when compared using the equals (=) operator. For this
>   definition, null values of a specified type are considered to compare
>   as equal. If one of the values in the expression list changes, the
>   **checksum of the list also generally changes. However, there is a small**
>   **chance that the checksum will not change.**

Thus, you may want to use [HAYSHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(v=SQL.100).aspx) instead

Answer (score 4):

This is an indirect answer to this old question, but in case someone arrives here looking for a way to get always-positive numbers (to save the hexadecimal representation, for example), try adding 2,147,483,648 to the result, getting values between 0 and 4,294,967,295.

Casting to bigint will be necessary:

```
DECLARE @k bigint = CAST(CHECKSUM(…) As bigint) + 2147483648;
```

Comment: Why not just use `ABS()` to ensure an always positive number?

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut If you are using `CHECKSUM()` as a hash function, you should try to avoid collisions. Since using `ABS()` removes the sign bit from the result, an _int 31_ is used instead of an int32.
This action reduces the number of hashes that will produce a 50% chance of collision from (roughly) 77,000 to 55,000. Therefore, with a simple addition, you can keep 32-bit working for you.

Comment: [Here, in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PLOT++1%E2%88%92exp%5B%E2%88%92k%28k%E2%88%921%29%2F%282*%282%5E32%29%29%5D+html+blue%2C++1%E2%88%92exp%5B%E2%88%92k%28k%E2%88%921%29%2F%282*%282%5E31%29%29%5D+html+red), you can see how dropping one bit makes the probability function steeper (31b red) than the other (32b blue).